# Retrieve configurations that are saved in db

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I saved all my system wide configurations in db. How do i make the configurations that I have saved in db available everywhere. These need to be available everywhere --in the model, view, controller, component, element etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to override the Configure::write() function with values that you are storing in the DB?  If not, then create a Settings model for your external settings and then pull that data when you need it in the controller.  You can then pass those settings to a view (and in turn elements), by following the normal MVC process.

Follow this process:

1. Create Settings Model
2. Add model to AppController's `$uses` array
3. Perform a find for the settings in your controller -- now the data
   is there
4. Pass the settings data to your view `$this->set('settings',
   $settings);`